# Adding a new operation to existing webservice

Tags: eclipse, web-services, wsdl

Can anyone suggest a good tutorial on how to add new operations to already existing webservices?I referred many tutorials but most are discussing about creating a new wsdl and then changing it.I also referred the following and when i tried it, the design view is not showing the names of existing ports.PLZ help by giving me suitable advice.

http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.wst.wsdl.ui.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftcrtwsdl.html

Answer (score 0):

If the web service already exists you can edit the existing interface and code behind to add the new operations.
Once you have done this you should be able to use a tool to generate a new WSDL which can be deployed along with your updated service.

The following tool; Java2WSDL should help, http://axis.apache.org/axis/java/user-guide.html#Java2WSDL:_Building_WSDL_from_Java

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I have webservice stubs generated from WSDL using Axis tool.By interface, did you mean those stubs?should i add my new function in that stub?

Answer (score -2):

Add an element in XSD file and map local part to new method in endpoint controller. `getCountryRequest` is existing operation in below XSD and I have added `getCountryByCurrencyRequest`.

```html
<xs:element name="getCountryRequest">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="getCountryResponse">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="country" type="tns:country" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="getCountryByCurrencyRequest">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```